# php json_encode addresses methods

Tags: php, json, encode

As far as i know, json encode url's like:

```
{"test":"testing","url":"http:\/\/google.com"}
```

For example bit.ly in json url handle like:

```
{"test":"testing","url":"http://google.com"}
```

1. Any benefit's using bit.ly method to show url's?
2. How to make appear url's like bit.ly do ? (code example needed)
3. What you guys suggesting to use and your opinion regarding these examples?

Comment: Both are equivalent *in Javascript*. But the JSON specification reserves an escape sequence for the forward slash. A very stringent JSON implementation might thus bail on a raw forward slash. (Even though it's generally unnecessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are equivalent and should work the same.

```
​alert('\/' === '/');​
```

[shows true](http://jsfiddle.net/jVNcv/).